# Firebase Database Table to link to image in Firebase Storage

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Im trying to create a table that will store the reference of the image in Firebase storage! The image is being uploaded and stored in Firebase Storage but I cant create the table to reference it in my database

Here is my code:

```
private async void UploadPhoto()
    {

        if (filePAth != null)
        {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progressDialog.SetTitle("Uploading...");
            progressDialog.Window.SetType(Android.Views.WindowManagerTypes.SystemAlert);
            progressDialog.Show();

            var images = storageRef.Child("images/" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            images.PutFile(filePAth)
                .AddOnProgressListener(this)
                .AddOnSuccessListener(this)
                .AddOnFailureListener(this);
        }


    }

public async void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {
        //get the logged on user so we know who made the category
        var user = FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser;

        //Link the photo in storage to database reference 
        try
        {
            var newImageDetails = storageRef.Child("images");
            Photo photos = new Photo();
            photos.categoryId = newImageDetails.Name;
            photos.photoId = newImageDetails.Name;
            photos.tagName = addTag.Text;

            if (user != null)
            {
                var uid = user.Uid;
                //set the users id to the category
                photos.uid = uid;
            }

            var firebase = new FirebaseClient(FirebaseURL);
            var item = await firebase.Child("photos").PostAsync(photos);
        }

        catch (System.Exception e)
        {

        }

        progressDialog.Dismiss();
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Successfully uploaded image", 
        ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
```

When I test with breakpoints the code says that the items are null in the try catch block?

Im trying to get the reference of the newly uploaded image!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

move your code of adding image url to firebaseDB inside the success listener of the images reference, since only after uploading the data the and success firebase gives you the url.

currently your code to get the link will not be waiting for the file to upload and then get the url

Comment: Ive tried this but when it comes to the line var newImageDetails = FirebaseStorage.Instance.Reference; its null and it skips over the rest of the code? Is there a way to get the reference of this newly uploaded image?

Comment: The reference of newly uploaded file is given in onSuccessListener method, from there you can actually upload the url of file to the firebasedb

Comment: Ive tried using this: var newImageDetails = storageRef.Child("images"); but it doesnt give me the information I want? Do you know what the code is to get the image reference?